# how to change the default GPU in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i want to change the default android GPU in the emulator.

[image]

I adjusted the graphics settings in the Windows settings(and amd radeon setting) but it didn't work.
[image: a]
[image: x]
[image: s]

**how can i change the default settings?**

Comment: AMD/ATI Panels should have something to choose GPU based on Process (similar to nVidia) where to choose which GPU use for each Process. Maybe Windows panel doesn't works well....

Comment: not additional setting found in my AMD panel (only found https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj8VB.png)

Comment: Did you set your Windows PowerManagement settings to High Performance? If PowerSaving (or maybe Balanced) is set it could not work as you expect...

Comment: thanks. yes i created new plan and sets to High Performance and i restarted my laptop. everything works(both graphic cards). please add answer and explain step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if Windows Power Management is set to "PowerSaving" (or maybe "Balanced") then it tries to use integrated GPU as much as it can even if the specific Process (exe) is listend in "*Execute this Application on Discrete GPU*".

So the first step is to add specific Executable (exe) to that List, and then set Windows Power Management to "Performance". In this way Windows will use Discrete GPU more often and will respect the List as expected.

Obliviously setting to "Performance" will consume more power and usually don't scale CPU GHz based on its load but usually remains always at high frequency (at least that's how it works on nVidia GPU/Drivers and Windows 10).